# How to style/theme grid's header checkbox in Vaadin flow?

Tags: vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid, vaadin10

I was trying to style Vaadin grids header, more specifically, I would like to change the background of the 'checkbox' to 'white'.

This changes all checkboxes to white, not just the one in the header.

```
:host [part="checkbox"] {
    background: white;
}

/*or*/
[part="checkbox"] {
    background: white;
}
```

Any suggestions on how I could accomplish that? See the screenshot below: 1) should have white background, 2) should stay with the default background, not white.

Tx.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the ID CSS selector?

```
#selectAllCheckbox {
    background: white;
}
```

As I can see on the grid components [demo page](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-grid/java-examples/selection), the check box is not part of the shadow DOM, i.e. you can style it using global CSS.